# как задать значение первым двум столбцам в двух мерном масиве

Tags: c#, .net

```
int[,] arr = new int[5, 5];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 10);       
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Как задать первым двум столбцам значение 0?

Comment: Что ты подразумеваешь под словом столбец? Если всем столбцам задать 0, то у тебя весь массив будет в нулях.

Comment: я скорее просто не понимаю как работать с индексами двух мерных масивов

Comment: изменил вопрос.

Comment: ответил на твой вопрос ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[,] arr = new int[5, 5];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = 0;       
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо странно что сам не догадался

Comment: @ильябелоусов https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level4/4_2.php - вот здесь есть картинка внутри статьи, где все наглядно показано по поводу "не понимаю как работать с индексами"